# Boostrap layout - Trying to align textarea in 2 columns layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 columns layout where each column is divided further into 2 more columns in each row. Now i am trying to extend text area field from 1st column(2nd child column) to 2nd column (4th child column) in the page and having hard time figuring out what bootstrap classes i am supposed to use.

I think it can be better described with this image:
[image]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpPxZZ

```css
.form-horizontal {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" id="formTest">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblFirstName" class="control-label col-xs-5">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <input type="textbox" class="form-control"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblLastname" class="control-label col-xs-5">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <input type="textbox" class="form-control"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblComments" class="control-label col-xs-5">Comments</label>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <textarea type="textbox" id="Comments" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change col-sm-6 to col-sm-12

BTW: Input tags doesnt have a closing tag, it just close.

**Incorrect:** 
`<input type="text"></input>`

**Correct:**
`<input type="text" />`

```css
.form-horizontal {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" id="formTest">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblFirstName" class="control-label col-xs-4">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <input type="textbox" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblLastname" class="control-label col-xs-4">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <input type="textbox" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblComments" class="control-label col-xs-2">Comments</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
          <textarea type="textbox" id="Comments" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: rookie mistake on that input part. when i run that code snippet here, it looks good but i am having the same layout issue as in codepen link where textarea comes over label place. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpPxZZ

Comment: @sanjeevshrestha change `col-sm-5` to `col-sm-4` and `col-sm-7` to `col-sm-8`. Look at how i have it

Comment: aah..got it. however they don't look good on small screen i.e. mobile device. etc. that's the reason i started using sm instead of xs on the first column definition.

Comment: Btw talking about that, you should set different column size for each screen, don't just use sm or xs.

Comment: alrite..may be that's what my issue then. thanks Luis.

Comment: Luis..that was one rabbit hole i got myself into. just couldn't get it to work just the way i wanted it. I think trying to make x-small screen to show just one label and textbox in one row and anything larger than that to show 2 labels and 2 textboxes in one row really killed my whole afternoon today. :(